# How are variables passed in laravel mails when using queue?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have set up my system so that users get a mail with their names when they successfully register and it works just fine. But i noticed that it takes a bit longer than i want for the page to display a success message so i decided to use laravel queue for background sending. Unfortunately member detail is added successfully but no mail is sent and the page error says

> Undefined property: App\Mail\Received::$name

Basically the following code is failing

```
$name = $newMember->firstname;

Mail::to($newMember)->queue(new Received($name));
```

While this one is working perfectly

```
$name = $newMember->firstname;

Mail::to($newMember)->send(new Received($name));
```

So the big question is why is the **$name** property undefined when i use queue but it's defined when i use send?

Comment: Can you post `App\Mail\Received` code

Comment: @SevaKalashnikov I have already provided the answer below. I will edit it to give a precise solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding `protected $name` property in `App\Mail\Received` class.